# How do dynamically enable/disable laravel packages from php

Tags: php, laravel, package, modular

I am building a laravel 5 modular application which the administrators will enable/disable functionalities(modules/packages) from backend.People say that I can have modular functionality with packages in laravel.So, I am using laravel packages as modules.As far as I know, we have to modify composer.json and app.php to install & uninstall a laravel package with composer or manually.I can modify those from my backend php scripts do dynamically enable/disable packages but I am not sure this is a recommended way to dynamically enable/disable laravel packages. So, can anyone tell me a recommended way to do this functionality please.

Comment: I got it now by following this : [link](https://github.com/bstrahija/laravel-modules-example)

Answer (score 2):

Check this link:

[Conditionally loading service providers](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/conditionally-loading-service-providers-in-laravel-5)

```
// AppServiceProvider.php

public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind(
        'Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Registrar',
        'App\Services\Registrar'
    );

    if ($this->app->environment('production')) {
        $this->app->register('App\Providers\ProductionErrorHandlerServiceProvider');
    } else {
        $this->app->register('App\Providers\VerboseErrorHandlerServiceProvider');
    }
}
```